# How to find a tuple in an array of unique intergers that add to a target number in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, tuples

I am trying to solve the first question of Advent of Code 2020 in Javascript. I am tasked with finding three numbers that add to a target number. In this case, the target is 2020.

For example:
There should be three numbers: `[1721, 979, 366, 299, 675, 1456]` that add to 2020. In this case, those numbers are `[366, 675, 979]`

My approach: By Sorting the array the efficiency of the algorithm can be improved. This efficient approach uses the two-pointer technique. Traverse the array and fix the first element of the triplet. Now use the Two Pointers algorithm to find if there is a pair whose sum is equal to x – array[i]. Two pointers algorithm take linear time so it is better than a nested loop.

Algorithm: Sort the given array.
Loop over the array and fix the first element of the possible triplet, arr[i].
Then fix two pointers, one at i + 1 and the other at n – 1. And look at the sum,
If the sum is smaller than the required sum, increment the first pointer.
Else, If the sum is bigger, Decrease the end pointer to reduce the sum.
Else, if the sum of elements at two-pointer is equal to given sum then print the triplet and break.

Note: I am expanding this approach from a python thread and really like it, but while trying to create it in javascript, I am having some trouble.

Currently, this is what I have:

```js
function threeSumBest(array, target) {

    // sort elements (accending)
    const sortedAsc = array.sort((a, b) => a - b)


    for (let i = 0; i < sortedAsc.length; i++) {
        let result = []

        // index of the first element in the remaining elements 
        let firstElement = i + 1

        // # index of the last element 
        let lastElement = sortedAsc.length - 1

        // create a sum variable
        let sum = (sortedAsc[i] + sortedAsc[firstElement] + sortedAsc[lastElement])

        // console.log(sortedAsc[i], sortedAsc[firstElement], sortedAsc[lastElement], sum);
        // console.log(sortedAsc[i], sortedAsc[firstElement], sortedAsc[lastElement]);
        console.log(result);

        if (sum > target) {
            console.log('greater than');
            lastElement--
        }
        if (sum < target) {
            console.log('less than');
            result[0] = sortedAsc[i++]
            result[1] = sortedAsc[firstElement]
            result[2] = sortedAsc[lastElement]
        }
        if (sum == target) {
            console.log('equal');
        }
    }
}

console.log(threeSumBest([1721, 979, 366, 299, 675, 1456], 2020))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the inner loop to iterate on firstIndex to lastIndex.
the following code will work for you

```
for (let i = 0; i < sortedAsc.length; i++) {
    let result = []

    // index of the first element in the remaining elements 
    let firstElement = i + 1

    // # index of the last element 
    let lastElement = sortedAsc.length - 1
    while(firstElement<lastElement){
        let sum = (sortedAsc[i] + sortedAsc[firstElement] + sortedAsc[lastElement])
        if (sum > target) {
            //console.log('greater than');
            firstElement++;
        }
        if (sum < target) {
            //console.log('less than');
            lastElement--;
        }
        if (sum == target) {
            result[0] = sortedAsc[i]
            result[1] = sortedAsc[firstElement]
            result[2] = sortedAsc[lastElement]
            console.log('equal');
            break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(threeSumBest([1721, 979, 366, 299, 675, 1456], 2020))
```